# django.db.utils.DatabaseError: permission denied for sequence

Tags: django, database, postgresql, permission-denied

After assigning the data to my database, and run command:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

I'm facing this error:

> django.db.utils.DatabaseError: permission denied for sequence log_action_id_seq

I tried pretty all of the ways suggested for solving sequence errors, none of them works!

Can anyone help to solve this issue please?

Comment: What version of django are you running?

Comment: the 1.4.22 version, and i'm forced to use this.

Comment: That is extremely insecure. I would fight tooth and nail to get away from it if I were you.

Comment: That's not my choice :)

Comment: I understand :/ Really sorry to hear that.

Comment: The only thing I can think of there though is some sort of user permission error.

Answer (score 0):

You should grant your DB user(one that Django uses) access to the following sequence

```
GRANT USAGE, SELECT  ON SEQUENCE log_action_id_seq TO dbuser;
```

or to all sequences in the schema

```
GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA name TO dbuser;
```

Comment: I tried these before, they don't work, the fist one face with error: 
ERROR:  schema "log_action" does not exist